# How to get the APIs from a Single Page Application?

Tags: reactjs, api, web-scraping

I'm browsing a web page which is a React SPA. There's some data I want to scrape but I was thinking if I can get it directly from the site API.

My question is: is there any way I can get the URL of the API(s) of a Single Page Application when browsing it?

Comment: well, you definitely can try to use the browser console to see the network calls, but it's unlikely that any good website with any basic amount of security will allow you to just make random calls against their server.....  That's called Cross Site Request Forgery, and most even basic APIs prevent it.

Comment: I've tried the network tab but with no success. I was wondering if it's an open API, but maybe you're right. Thank you.

Comment: @Claies - csrf tokens don't prevent *you* from making requests, it prevents other sites from doing so.

Comment: @pguardiario isn’t that exactly what this question is asking how to do?

Comment: If it isn't coming from a XHR (which you would see in the Network tab) then it's probably in a big json object in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight-forward answer to this question. But you can try one of these two methods.

1. **Inspect the dev tools** to get the API endpoints
2. If the site has docs, you can check if there are **docs** for their API

But mostly, you'll have problems accessing the API if the site is not open to exposing their API.

1. **CORS prevention**. They might not let you or anyone make API calls to their API. Only their site will be allowed to make API calls.
2. **Tokens**. If the tokens have a quicky expiry, you will have to find a way to obtain tokens often.

Comment: CORS is a browser security feature, so it almost never applies to scraping and definitely doesn't here.

Comment: @pguardiario The OP is not asking about scraping. The OP wants to get the data directly from the API _instead_ of scraping. Also, **CORS** is a server configuration. Browsers by default disable CORS unless the server asks the browsers to _allow-cors_ explicitly in the response headers.

Comment: You can read more about _CORS_ here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: No, he specifically says "scrape". If he is making the request from a python script (most common) there is no CORS preflight. And if he is making it from the browser context it will pass. Also, CORS can be easily disabled.

Comment: _"Also, CORS can be easily disabled."_

Wait what? Even if the server is set to not allow _CORS_ requests?

Comment: Yes but you're missing the point. There is no way that CORS could apply in this case.

Comment: @pguardiario I've been humbled. Thanks for bringing this up. I'll dig deep into it.

Comment: Right, I think what's happening is that you're a web developer and so you're projecting your struggles with CORS onto the question but if you read it again (esp the tags) you'll see OP is not a react dev, but rather a lowly scraper trying to scrape a react app, which is a whole other thing.

Comment: In this specific case I couldn't see any XHR in the dev tools because the data wasn't being fetched from an API, it was being rendered by the server in a big JSON object in a script tag in the end of the index.html. That's it. Thank you everybody.